cordova-built android app can't open in studio
I use create a new cordova application and run cordova platform add android, then I run cordova build without modifying the original content. And I got this :
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 37s
1 actionable task: 1 up-to-date
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1m 50s
50 actionable tasks: 50 up-to-date
Built the following apk(s):
        D:\projects\1\com.test.new\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk

But when I open this with Android studio, it says app-debug.apk is unsupported binary file
I want to compile it and install it

Just use ADB to install the .apk

I tried the both and it still throw the same error
